# htaccess proxy rewrites stop working after server reboot on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, .htaccess, centos7, mod-proxy

I'm on CentOS 7, EasyApache 4. I have some .htaccess rewrites that look like:

```
RewriteRule ^slug/(.*)$ http://mybucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/slug/$1? [P,L]
```

in order to rewrite requests for static files to my s3 bucket. This works fine, until I reboot the server, then it stops working. Apache is running, and the website loads, but all requests to files at /slug get 404s. But, if I then manually restart apache, it starts working again and the images load. I'm using the [P] tag so that all files are under the SSL certificate on my local server.

Any idea what might be going on here? Even if you have a hint for how to begin troubleshooting this, that would help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I found in the apache error logs, that for each proxied image, I'm getting [proxy error] ... DNS lookup failure for: (my s3 url)

Comment: How do you resolve your addresses ? External dns ?

Comment: I haven't done anything on the server to change whatever the default way a CentOS server would resolve external addresses. I suppose it would check some local cache or hosts file, and then query an external DNS server if the host wasn't found. I guess my problem is, my server can't resolve the URL to my s3 bucket, unless I restart apache, then it will.

Comment: Before restarting apache can you resolve the domain from the system ?

Comment: I can ping the s3 url from the command line, and I get a response. Any other way I can check that?

Comment: Some more information: if I disable Name Service Caching Daemon on the server, this problem goes away. Also, in my boot.log, I have this line: Dependency failed for Network Manager Wait Online.

Comment: My solution for now is to just leave nscd disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `EasyApache` starts before network. This cause error `DNS lookup failure`. As workaround, you could add address of your S3 bucket in `/etc/hosts` file or add `After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target` to `[Unit]` section in service file, to start EasyApache after network is up, as it done in Apache service file.

Comment: Sounds like a good reason for having DNS lookup failure, but how can apache start before ? Isn't it supposed to do some binding on the network interface ?

Comment: @daftaupe if it binds on 0.0.0.0 it's possible.

Comment: I can't add the ip address of the s3 bucket, because s3 buckets don't have static ip addresses. But, even if apache starts before network on reboot, shouldn't apache be able to resolve the address after reboot is completed and network has started up? I'm observing DNS lookup failures indefintely, until I restart apache.

Comment: Also, what is the service file that you're referring to where I would add the line you suggested?

Comment: @user339568 it should be `/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service`.

Comment: Thanks, Alexander, this file wasn't there, but I tried creating it and adding the line you suggested under the [Unit] section, and I rebooted, and the problem remains. Is there anything else I would need to do after creating the file?

Comment: @user339568 don't create it there. I checked EasyApache SPEC file and found that it should be in `/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service`. Please check it.

Comment: Ok, that worked. I added this line to that file, and re-enabled nscd and booted, and the proxies are now working without restarting apache. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @user339568 I made a [PR](https://github.com/CpanelInc/ea-apache2/pull/5) on GitHub to prevent such issues in future.